# zend onChange submit

Tags: php, javascript, forms, zend-framework, submit

i'm trying to submit a form with the event "onchange" on a Zend_Form_Element_Select but i dont succeed. with a simple button Zend_Form_Element_Submit i dont have probleme, but impossible with the onchange on my liste.

the code on my form:

```
$this->setName('myparamcliform');
$this->setAttrib('id', 'myformm');
$this->setAction('/first/second/index');

$Liste5 = new zend_psai_Liste();
$ListeActivite = $Liste5->ListeActivite();
$activite = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('activite',array('onchange' => "alert('hello 6');;"));
    $activite->setLabel('')
          ->setMultiOptions($ListeActivite);
```

there is no problem with a simple alert message, but when i replace it by a submit function, it doesn't work.
different element found on the web (thanks stackoverflow :) ) i tryed :

```
    //documents.forms['myformm'].submit();
    //document.myparamcliform.submit();
    //->setAttrib('onChange', "this.form.submit();");
    //document.getElementById('myformm').submit()
    //,array('onchange' => 'this.form.submit();')

    $mysubmit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('mysubmit');
    $mysubmit->setLabel('RECHERCHER');

    $this->addElements(array($activite,$mysubmit));
```

with these different solution, it doesn't work. no error message and no action with the "onchange", but no probleme with the simple alert message.

Comment: What do you mean saying `no error message`? Have you checked browser console? Do you have any other JS attached to form submit event (validation or something like that...)?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't assign a *class* or *id* to a button and bind a function to it which will be in *some.js* file?

It will work for sure and this way you will increase maintainability of your scripts. Simple functions like `alert()` is *ok* to write inline, but more complex scripts better to put separately from the template.